# Configuring SASL with kerberos

Tags: ldap, kerberos, sasl

This is my first time configuring SASL, and I am lost.

I have a samba 4 as AD controller, and have installed kerberos.
kinit is already succesful, but SASL cannot authenticate anything

I have tried to set as kerberos, and error is this:

```
root@mail:/usr/lib/sasl2# saslauthd -a kerberos5 -d
saslauthd[20269] :main            : num_procs  : 5
saslauthd[20269] :main            : mech_option: NULL
saslauthd[20269] :main            : run_path   : /var/run/saslauthd
saslauthd[20269] :main            : auth_mech  : kerberos5
saslauthd[20269] :ipc_init        : using accept lock file: /var/run/saslauthd/mux.accept
saslauthd[20269] :detach_tty      : master pid is: 0
saslauthd[20269] :ipc_init        : listening on socket: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
saslauthd[20269] :main            : using process model
saslauthd[20269] :have_baby       : forked child: 20270
saslauthd[20270] :get_accept_lock : acquired accept lock
saslauthd[20269] :have_baby       : forked child: 20271
saslauthd[20269] :have_baby       : forked child: 20272
saslauthd[20269] :have_baby       : forked child: 20273
saslauthd[20270] :rel_accept_lock : released accept lock
saslauthd[20271] :get_accept_lock : acquired accept lock
saslauthd[20270] :do_auth         : auth failure: [user=prd] [service=imap] [realm=innowareindonesia.co.id] [mech=kerberos5] [reason=saslauthd internal error]
```

when I try using LDAP, error is this:

```
root@mail:/usr/lib/sasl2# saslauthd -a ldap -d
saslauthd[20275] :main            : num_procs  : 5
saslauthd[20275] :main            : mech_option: NULL
saslauthd[20275] :main            : run_path   : /var/run/saslauthd
saslauthd[20275] :main            : auth_mech  : ldap
saslauthd[20275] :ipc_init        : using accept lock file: /var/run/saslauthd/mux.accept
saslauthd[20275] :detach_tty      : master pid is: 0
saslauthd[20275] :ipc_init        : listening on socket: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
saslauthd[20275] :main            : using process model
saslauthd[20275] :have_baby       : forked child: 20276
saslauthd[20276] :get_accept_lock : acquired accept lock
saslauthd[20275] :have_baby       : forked child: 20277
saslauthd[20275] :have_baby       : forked child: 20278
saslauthd[20275] :have_baby       : forked child: 20279
saslauthd[20276] :rel_accept_lock : released accept lock
saslauthd[20277] :get_accept_lock : acquired accept lock
saslauthd[20276] :do_auth         : auth failure: [user=prd] [service=imap] [realm=innowareindonesia.co.id] [mech=ldap] [reason=Unknown]
saslauthd[20276] :do_request      : response: NO
```

this is my /etc/saslauthd.conf

```
root@mail:/usr/lib/sasl2# cat /etc/saslauthd.conf
ldap_servers: ldaps://auth.innowareindonesia.co.id:636/
ldap_version: 3
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_search_base: cn=Users,dc=innowareindonesia,dc=co,dc=id
ldap_filter: (|(UserPrincipalName=%u)(sAMAccountName=%u))
ldap_scope: sub
```

this is what my pluginviewer result

```
root@mail:/usr/lib/sasl2# saslpluginviewer
Installed and properly configured auxprop mechanisms are:
sasldb sasldb
List of auxprop plugins follows
Plugin "sasldb" ,       API version: 8
        supports store: yes

Plugin "sasldb" ,       API version: 8
        supports store: yes

Installed and properly configured SASL (server side) mechanisms are:
  GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GSSAPI GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 EXTERNAL CRAM-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS
Available SASL (server side) mechanisms matching your criteria are:
  GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GSSAPI GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS
List of server plugins follows
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: yes
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: yes
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: yes
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: yes
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features:
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features:
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features:
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features:
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0, supports setpass: no
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|DONTUSE_USERPASSWD
Installed and properly configured SASL (client side) mechanisms are:
  GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GSSAPI GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 EXTERNAL CRAM-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS
Available SASL (client side) mechanisms matching your criteria are:
  GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 GSSAPI GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 EXTERNAL CRAM-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS
List of client plugins follows
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-IAKERB, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gs2" [loaded],  API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GS2-KRB5, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|GSS_FRAMING|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "scram" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|CHANNEL_BINDING
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|NEED_SERVER_FQDN
Plugin "gssapiv2" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: GSSAPI, best SSF: 56
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_ACTIVE|PASS_CREDENTIALS|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|NEED_SERVER_FQDN
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "digestmd5" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: DIGEST-MD5, best SSF: 128
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|MUTUAL_AUTH
        features: PROXY_AUTHENTICATION|NEED_SERVER_FQDN|SUPPORTS_HTTP
Plugin "EXTERNAL" [loaded],     API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: EXTERNAL, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT|NO_DICTIONARY
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST
Plugin "crammd5" [loaded],      API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: CRAM-MD5, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "ntlm" [loaded],         API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: NTLM, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "plain" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: PLAIN, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST|PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
Plugin "login" [loaded],        API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: LOGIN, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_ANONYMOUS|PASS_CREDENTIALS
        features: SERVER_FIRST
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST
Plugin "anonymous" [loaded],    API version: 4
        SASL mechanism: ANONYMOUS, best SSF: 0
        security flags: NO_PLAINTEXT
        features: WANT_CLIENT_FIRST
```

Can someone please help? Because I am already pulling my hair on this for 3 months, and on verge of smashing my monitor. I don't know what is going on, and I don't know where to find anything. No debugging, no log, no trace, no nothing that can talk to me what happenned, it just said "error" and "unknown" without specifying what error orlet me know where this error comes from, and google gave me nothing.

I want to know what's going on, and whats wrong. How to enable debug, how to make saslauthd talk to me what is going on?

And there is no traffic sent outside. tcpdump shows nothing. I guess this is purely sasl configuration.

Comment: If your Krb5 is recent enough, then export `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr` before starting saslauthd. Also, if you're asking about Kerberos, then the LDAP configuration in saslauthd.conf is irrelevant...

Comment: Wow.. thank you.. if you put this as answer, I'll vote for it. They should put this in their documentation. It seems that kerberos couldn't find my entry table. I can fix that myself. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to know what's going on, and whats wrong. How to enable debug, how to make saslauthd talk to me what is going on?*

Recent MIT Kerberos 5 versions (1.9 and above) support the `KRB5_TRACE` environment variable for detailed Krb5 and GSSAPI logs. Export `KRB5_TRACE="/dev/stderr"` before starting saslauthd, and it'll show the server status.

*(Note: Heimdal Kerberos does not support this yet.)*

Another approach is the `strace` tool, which shows syscalls performed by a process. For example, it will show you if saslauthd tries to open a file but receives an error code:

```
open("/etc/krb5.keytab", O_RDONLY)      = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

While strace is Linux-only, other operating systems have alternatives: ktrace, dtrace, truss...

Finally, one could compile the Cyrus libsasl from source, adding *custom* error messages all over, and repeat until the problem is found (aka "printf debugging").